# Prevent action from execution

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to prevent an action from execution if user types same action and controller in url in mvc4.Suppose I am having Action name as "Prevent" in controller name as "MyDept".Now I want to prevent this action from execution like if user types www.mysite.com/MyDept/Prevent then 404 error or page not found error should be diplayed.

Comment: Why have a action method if you don't want it to be accessed?

Comment: make it a private or protected method... that's one way of doing it. The other is decorating it by the NoAction attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have a method in your **controller** that you **don't** want it to **be accessed** decorate it with `[NonAction]` attribute.